# 3704 error Operation is not allowed when the object is closed - IBM server client 10.5

Tags: vb6

I have VB 6.0 windows application and the backend is db2. I'm uisng ODBC (DSNP and DSNT) connections to connect to the DB2. My application works fine with the driver IBM server client 9.7 . When I run the same application with IBM Server Client 10.5 it throws an error '3704 error Operation is not allowed when the object is closed' when I open the adodb recordset in code.
The same VB 6.0 code works fine for IBM Server Client 9.7

My .Net applications are working fine in both the driver IBM Server Client 9.7 and IBM Server Client 10.5.

Please anyone help me out to solve this issue.

```
Dim rstStaticData As New ADODB.Recordset

   Dim SQL As String
   Dim RecordCount As Integer
   Dim I As Integer

   On Error GoTo QueryError

   Query = 0

   SQL = "select * from employee"

   rstStaticData.Open SQL, adoConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

I am getting the error in the above line of the code. I checked the status of  adoconn object and it is active.

Comment: your code does not show any "connection" string - maybe there is a difference between the old and the new version.

Comment: Hi Kasebrot, I have opened the connection in another function and just passed the connection object here. There is no prob with conenction.